# Any TV news pieces/stickers?

Tags: bricklink, part-database, sticker-identification

I'm looking for pieces to make a TV transmitting news. I looked on Bricklink "News" sets but only found 2 existed. Does anyone know of any set that contains a news anchor on TV piece or sticker?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few that I'm aware of.

Here's [one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87079pb022) from the [7208 Fire Station](https://brickset.com/sets/7208-1):

[image: Fire TV]

And [another](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87079pb073) from the [7288 Mobile Police Unit](https://brickset.com/sets/7288-1):

[image: Police TV]

[This TV element](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3068bpb0187) from the 7639 Camper may also work for you:

[image: Camper TV]

These are all very affordable on Bricklink. Note that they are stickered parts. I'm not aware of printed parts with this pattern, but perhaps someone else here knows of some.

Comment: 10202pb009 may also be suitable.

Answer (score 1):

The trend I found on *Bricklink* is a news icon graphic with an image of a lined globe and the letters "TV".  [image]

*[This](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6553-1)* is the earliest set that has multiple iconography with this Globe TV theme.
[image]

This theme evolves in later sets to TV 6+ News Channel/Station still sporting a lined Globe.
[image]

[Here](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60233-1) is a set with this modification on that TV6 theme.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick search for "tv" provides a [list of 57 parts](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=tv#T=P&P=1) on Bricklink.